rails 6.1 inconsistent behavior when using framwork_default_6_1.rb vs load_defaults = 6.1
I am upgrading my project from 6.0 to 6.1 and in my project, I have
config/initializers/new_framework_defaults_6_0.rb
# Be sure to restart your server when you modify this file.
#
# This file contains migration options to ease your Rails 6.0 upgrade.
#
# Once upgraded flip defaults one by one to migrate to the new default.
#
# Read the Guide for Upgrading Ruby on Rails for more info on each option.

# Don't force requests from old versions of IE to be UTF-8 encoded.
Rails.application.config.action_view.default_enforce_utf8 = false

# Embed purpose and expiry metadata inside signed and encrypted
# cookies for increased security.
#
# This option is not backwards compatible with earlier Rails versions.
# It's best enabled when your entire app is migrated and stable on 6.0.
Rails.application.config.action_dispatch.use_cookies_with_metadata = true

# Change the return value of `ActionDispatch::Response#content_type` to Content-Type header without modification.
# Rails.application.config.action_dispatch.return_only_media_type_on_content_type = false

# Return false instead of self when enqueuing is aborted from a callback.
# Rails.application.config.active_job.return_false_on_aborted_enqueue = true

# Send Active Storage analysis and purge jobs to dedicated queues.
# Rails.application.config.active_storage.queues.analysis = :active_storage_analysis
# Rails.application.config.active_storage.queues.purge    = :active_storage_purge

# When assigning to a collection of attachments declared via `has_many_attached`, replace existing
# attachments instead of appending. Use #attach to add new attachments without replacing existing ones.
Rails.application.config.active_storage.replace_on_assign_to_many = true

# Use ActionMailer::MailDeliveryJob for sending parameterized and normal mail.
#
# The default delivery jobs (ActionMailer::Parameterized::DeliveryJob, ActionMailer::DeliveryJob),
# will be removed in Rails 6.1. This setting is not backwards compatible with earlier Rails versions.
# If you send mail in the background, job workers need to have a copy of
# MailDeliveryJob to ensure all delivery jobs are processed properly.
# Make sure your entire app is migrated and stable on 6.0 before using this setting.
# Rails.application.config.action_mailer.delivery_job = 'ActionMailer::MailDeliveryJob'

# Enable the same cache key to be reused when the object being cached of type
# `ActiveRecord::Relation` changes by moving the volatile information (max updated at and count)
# of the relation's cache key into the cache version to support recycling cache key.
Rails.application.config.active_record.collection_cache_versioning = true


config/initializers/new_framework_defaults_6_1.rb
# Be sure to restart your server when you modify this file.
#
# This file contains migration options to ease your Rails 6.1 upgrade.
#
# Once upgraded flip defaults one by one to migrate to the new default.
#
# Read the Guide for Upgrading Ruby on Rails for more info on each option.

# Support for inversing belongs_to -> has_many Active Record associations.
Rails.application.config.active_record.has_many_inversing = true

# Track Active Storage variants in the database.
Rails.application.config.active_storage.track_variants = true

# Apply random variation to the delay when retrying failed jobs.
Rails.application.config.active_job.retry_jitter = 0.15

# Stop executing `after_enqueue`/`after_perform` callbacks if
# `before_enqueue`/`before_perform` respectively halts with `throw :abort`.
Rails.application.config.active_job.skip_after_callbacks_if_terminated = true

# Specify cookies SameSite protection level: either :none, :lax, or :strict.
#
# This change is not backwards compatible with earlier Rails versions.
# It's best enabled when your entire app is migrated and stable on 6.1.
Rails.application.config.action_dispatch.cookies_same_site_protection = :lax

# Generate CSRF tokens that are encoded in URL-safe Base64.
#
# This change is not backwards compatible with earlier Rails versions.
# It's best enabled when your entire app is migrated and stable on 6.1.
Rails.application.config.action_controller.urlsafe_csrf_tokens = true

# Specify whether `ActiveSupport::TimeZone.utc_to_local` returns a time with an
# UTC offset or a UTC time.
ActiveSupport.utc_to_local_returns_utc_offset_times = true

# Change the default HTTP status code to `308` when redirecting non-GET/HEAD
# requests to HTTPS in `ActionDispatch::SSL` middleware.
Rails.application.config.action_dispatch.ssl_default_redirect_status = 308

# Use new connection handling API. For most applications this won't have any
# effect. For applications using multiple databases, this new API provides
# support for granular connection swapping.
Rails.application.config.active_record.legacy_connection_handling = false

# Make `form_with` generate non-remote forms by default.
Rails.application.config.action_view.form_with_generates_remote_forms = false

# Set the default queue name for the analysis job to the queue adapter default.
Rails.application.config.active_storage.queues.analysis = nil

# Set the default queue name for the purge job to the queue adapter default.
Rails.application.config.active_storage.queues.purge = nil

# Set the default queue name for the incineration job to the queue adapter default.
Rails.application.config.action_mailbox.queues.incineration = nil

# Set the default queue name for the routing job to the queue adapter default.
Rails.application.config.action_mailbox.queues.routing = nil

# Set the default queue name for the mail deliver job to the queue adapter default.
Rails.application.config.action_mailer.deliver_later_queue_name = nil

# Generate a `Link` header that gives a hint to modern browsers about
# preloading assets when using `javascript_include_tag` and `stylesheet_link_tag`.
# Rails.application.config.action_view.preload_links_header = true

and in application.rb I am using config.load_defaults = 6.0 and run test cases everything works fine. As soon as I remove the file config/initializers/new_framework_defaults_6_1.rb  and add below block in application.rb
if $next_rails
      config.load_defaults 6.1
    else
      config.load_defaults 6.0
    end

everything fails there are so many test cases failing with error
RuntimeError: Wrapped undumpable exception for: ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique: PG::UniqueViolation: ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "as_bs_unique"
DETAIL:  Key (a_id, b_id)=(493764392, 897260172) already exists.

Error:
RuntimeError: Wrapped undumpable exception for: ActiveRecord::NotNullViolation: PG::NotNullViolation: ERROR:  null value in column "site_id" of relation "xyz_tags" violates not-null constraint
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (16, null, 16).


I am not able to proceed further. Does anyone else faced such issue. Thanks in advance for help.ruby

Not too sure what change triggered these errors but maybe you can try investigate the errors. The second one seems to be a simple one-to-many relationship where a record is missing a site_id. Maybe you can make the relationship optional if some children are ok to have no parent and see what happens

Thanks @Maxence let me play around it.
